# Rsync (No need to copy the time stamp)

Tags: rsync

With `rsync` command I want only copy/sync changed files/folder to the destination folder. I had some issue with Rsync-like whenever am executing the `rsync` command am copied along with the time stamp as well.

For example, my destination folder ‘Linux’ had updated on 1 month back and in my source folder there is no update info for the 'Linux' folder, but when am performing the `rsync` command my destination 'Linux' folder time stamp has been updated with latest source folder time stamp. I don’t want to copy the timestamp. please suggest me on this and please glance on below command which I have used.

```
rsync -avh /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux/ 

rsync -uan /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux/

rsync -uav /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux/
```

Comment: You __do__ want to copy the timestamps, these will be used when you run `rsync` next time to find out what has changed.  The alternative is to use checksums, which are much slower.

Answer (score 10):

The `-a` option (`--archive`) implies the `-t` option (`--times`, "preserve modification times").

You may negate this option using either `--no-t` or `--no-times` *after* `-a`:

```
rsync -a --no-t /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux/
```

This would not copy the source timestamps to the destination.  Note though, that `rsync` compares timestamps (and other metadata) to determine whether files are updated and needs copying.  You may therefore want to use `-u` (`--update`) too.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kusalananda. I have already tried like- rsync -rlpgoD /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux/. Actually -a represent -rlptgoD so on this I have eliminated the 't' option and tried but no luck.

Comment: `rsync -rlvi` sets all the file modification timestamps to now.. I think the goal was to not change them at all.

Comment: @adfaklsdjf Note that "not copying the remote timestamps" is not the same as "preserving the timestamps locally".  My answer concerns "not copying the remote timestamps", as this is what the user asks about.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you *should* copy the timestamps, because this allows `rsync` to run more efficiently in future.

But there may be times when you really don't want to keep the timestamps in sync.  For example, `git` keeps changing the timestamps on your files, but when you run rsync you don't want to see these timestamps being transferred, you only want to see the files which have really changed.

`--no-times` will avoid copying the timestamp, but if a file *is* updated, the target file will have its modification time set to *now*.  That means the timestamps will now differ, so the next `rsync` will think an update is needed, and will send it again!

To avoid this, `--ignore-times` **will not help**, because it causes all files to be updated.

What you can do is use `--checksum`, which is hard work for rsync, but it will do what you want: it will ignore the timestamps, and only update a file if its actual *contents* have changed.

So you might like to use a command like this:

```bash
rsync -i -a --no-times --checksum /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux
```

### Alternative approach

If you want to keep rsync efficient, then you should keep the timestamps in sync.

But if you don't want to see updates which are *only* timestamp changes, then you can hide these from the output:

```bash
rsync -ai /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux |
grep --line-buffered -v '^.[fd]\.\.t\.\.\.\.\.\. '
```

Please note that if you take this approach, you will get `grep`'s exit code, instead of `rsync`'s!  So this may not be suitable for scripting, because the exit code may be misleading.  You can work around that using [pipefail or PIPESTATUS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46400979/99777).

In the end, I used this:

```bash
rsync_ai_with_quiet_timestamps() {
  # This will not send timestamps, and not check timestamps, but it is slow
  #rsync -a --no-times --checksum -i "$@"

  # This will send timestamps, but hide updates which are only timestamp changes
  (
    set +e
    rsync -ai "$@" |
    grep --line-buffered -v '^.[fd][.][.]t[.][.][.][.][.][.] '
    exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
  )
}

...

rsync_ai_with_quiet_timestamps /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux
```